# System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

Tags: c#

Guys can some one tell me why i have such error ....

```
2013-08-11 18:44:28 - NPMessage: DEBUG: Dispatching a RPCStorageWriteUserFileMessage
2013-08-11 18:44:28 - RPCStorageWriteUserFileMessage: INFO: Got a request for writing 8192 bytes to file iw4.stat for user alhpons.
2013-08-11 18:44:28 - ProfileData: INFO: Handling profile update request for alhpons
2013-08-11 18:44:28 - ProfileData: ERROR: Exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\IW4M\NpServer\data\priv2\00\000\alhpons\iw4.stat' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String path)
   at NPx.ProfileData.Handle(UpdateRequest request)
   at NPx.ProfileData.Run()
```

Edit:

i use my App on windows server 2008 and some files need to read / write permission for my application but i have such error so i need to fix that problem and my source is:

```
public override void Process(NPHandler client)
    {
        var fileName = Message.fileName;
        var fileData = Message.fileData;
        var npid = (long)Message.npid;
        var fsFile = StorageUtils.GetFilename(fileName, npid);

        _client = client;
        _fileName = fileName;
        _npid = npid;

        if (!client.Authenticated)
        {
            ReplyWithError(1);
            return;
        }

        if (client.NPID != (long)npid)
        {
            ReplyWithError(1);
            return;
        }

        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(fsFile)))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fsFile));
        }

        // are we allowed to write this type of file?
        if (!_fileHooks.ContainsKey(fileName))
        {
            ReplyWithError(1);
            return;
        }

        string backupFile = null;

        int result = _fileHooks[fileName](fileData, fsFile, out backupFile);

        if (result > 0)
        {
            ReplyWithError(result);
            return;
        }

        Log.Info(string.Format("Got a request for writing {0} bytes to file {1} for user {2}.", fileData.Length, fileName, npid.ToString("X16")));

        try
        {
            var stream = File.Open(fsFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            stream.BeginWrite(fileData, 0, fileData.Length, WriteCompleted, stream);

            if (backupFile != null)
            {
                var backupStream = File.Open(backupFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

                backupStream.BeginWrite(fileData, 0, fileData.Length, BackupWriteCompleted, backupStream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.ToString());
            ReplyWithError(2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `2013-08-11 18:44:28 - ProfileData: ERROR: Exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\IW4M\NpServer\data\priv2\00\000\alhpons\iw4.stat' because it is being used by another process.` Where do you try to write/read from this file? Show the relevant code.

Comment: what part of " because it is being used by another process" is unclear?

Comment: File used by same application and there is no such error on my app its just system error

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the very program that gives you this message may be the program that is locking the file.  Make sure to practice good housekeeping by closing each data stream after it has been used.

Answer (score 2):

```
  var stream = File.Open(fsFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

Where do you close this stream again?

> The process cannot access the file xxx because it is being used by another process.

The Microsoft programmer that wrote this message was a trust-hearty soul.  He did not want to assume that you got it wrong.  When you are debugging your code, that message should however have ended with "is being used by a process".  It includes your own.

Also note that you made the same mistake with *backupStream*.  Since you are already using File.ReadAllBytes() to read the file, you might just as well use File.WriteAllBytes() to write it.  If you can't afford the delay then you'll need to ensure it is closed in the WriteCompeted callback method.

If you already do this, then consider that the file might actually be in use by another process.  Which *does* happen.

Comment: Full source not found: This paste has been removed

Answer (score -1):

Based on the information provided, the error System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) is being thrown when the program is trying to write data to a file that is currently being used by another process.

If a file is being used by another process, any attempts to access that file will result in an IOException.

Here’s a potential solution:

```
public override void Process(NPHandler client)
{
    // ... existing code ...

    try
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(fsFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            stream.BeginWrite(fileData, 0, fileData.Length, WriteCompleted, stream);
        }

        if (backupFile != null)
        {
            using (var backupStream = new FileStream(backupFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                backupStream.BeginWrite(fileData, 0, fileData.Length, BackupWriteCompleted, backupStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.ToString());
        ReplyWithError(2);
    }

    // ... existing code ...
}
```

In this modified code, I’ve wrapped the FileStream objects in using statements. This ensures that the FileStream is correctly disposed of once it’s no longer needed, which should free up the file for other processes to use. This might help to prevent the IOException from being thrown.